# Almost all Customers deleted

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I have a magento 2.1.4 site. My client has admin access
Today he exported all clients to an XLS file.

Something happened and all customers are gone...
How is this even possible, even customers with orders...

Is there any log of deletes ?
I suspect this was some kind of user error... How can i be certain ?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome. You need to provide more details

Comment: I don't have any, i am baffled, client says he exported and then they were gone... The site was migrated from another server (not by me so i don't know, maybe something happened then...

Comment: Data backup should be regular, every week minimum. That is a must for any professional site. That won't save everything but that will save a lot of data. Did you setup regular data backup and if not, why not and also never do this again?

Comment: Already restored the backup. The server has daily backup and about a week retention. I was just trying to understand what happened